# Should I have to submit the third party app on app store before submitting the app for approval on Instagram

Tags: instagram-api

I am developing an IOS app and now I want to submit the app for Instagram approval. 
So before submitting the app for Instagram approval should I need to submit the app on app Store?

Comment: no, get Instagram approval first by sending a screen cast and detailed explaination

Comment: thanks for the information